# tailwind css justify between inside a absolute div not working

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

i am using Tailwind CSS and I want to place my navbar on top on a image ,
and its mainly an image in relative position and my navbar on absolute position,
without the absolute  or

, i am able to make the item justify-between, however, if it is inside a "absolute"  or

, it didnt work as expected.

my code  was as follow:

```
    <div className='container max-w-full'>
        <div className='h-screen w-full'>
            {/* <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${banner.src})`,
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    opacity: '50%'}}>

            </div> */}
            <div className="relative w-max inset-0 -z-1">
                <Image 
                    src= {banner} 
                    alt="ic"
                    sizes="100vw"                       
                    className="w-full h-auto opacity-50"
                />
            </div>
            <h2 className='absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 text-slate-700'>
                <div className='flex flex-col space-y-5 justify-center items-center text-center'>
                    <div className='text-7xl font-bold'>
                        Title
                    </div>
                    <div className='text-7xl'>
                        Title text
                    </div>
                    <button className='text-2xl bg-sky-700 text-white px-10 py-5 rounded-lg'>
                        Explore
                    </button>
                </div>
            </h2>
            <p className='absolute top-0'>
                <div className='flex justify-between'>
                    <div className='text-3xl p-2'>
                            Logo
                    </div>
                    <div className='text-3xl p-2'>
                        Menu
                    </div>
                    <div className='text-3xl p-2'>
                        Menu2
                    </div>

                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the part of

```
                <p className='absolute top-0'>
                <div className='flex justify-center items-center text-center'>
                    <div className='text-3xl p-2'>
                            Logo
                    </div>
                    <div className='text-3xl p-2'>
                        Menu
                    </div>
                    <div className='text-3xl p-2'>
                        Menu2
                    </div>

                </div>
            </p>
```

it didn't make the items justify between , instead it all stay on top-0 left-0 position,

i would appreciate if someone can help thanks

Comment: The portion you highlighted shows `justify-center` so it definitely would not justify the content between. Besides that you cannot put divs inside a paragraph tag, it's not valid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are giving an element the `position: absolute` style, you must specify its `width` so that the child element has enough room to preserve the space between each child element.

Note: Since `div` cannot be used inside the `p` tag I used nav.

```
 <nav className='w-full absolute top-0'>
     <div className='flex justify-between items-center text-center'>
            <div className='text-3xl p-2'>
               Logo
            </div>
            <div className='text-3xl p-2'>
               Menu
            </div>
            <div className='text-3xl p-2'>
               Menu2
            </div>
     </div>
 </nav>
```